# Scala Function syntax

Tags: scala, function

I am currently learning Scala using a tutorial, and I have come across a syntax I do not understand (and I haven not found the answer):

```
object Demo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     println(apply(layout, 10))
   }

   def apply(f: Int => String, v: Int) = f(v)

   def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
}
```

In

```
def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
```

I do not understand the [A] after layout and before the argument declaration.

Is it the return type?

For me the general syntax for a function in scala is the following;

```
def functionName ([list of parameters]) : [return type] = {
   function body
   return [expr]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is something called a type parameter. Type parameters allow you to write a method, generically, for any `A`. It could be that `A` is an `Int`, `Double`, or even a custom class you've written. Since all of these have a `toString` method inherited from `Any`, this will work.

For example, when we do:

```
println(layout(1L))
println(layout(1f))
```

This is identical to writing:

```
println(layout[Long](1L))
println(layout[Float](1f))
```

Where the *type parameters* are explicitly passed.

Comment: If you know Java, this is roughly equivalent to how they annotate generic methods with `<A>`.

Comment: In this case, does it do anything useful, though? Why not just `def layout(x: Any)`?

Comment: @Thilo In this particular example, it's not too meaningful. One could use `Any` and achieve the same thing. When one writes a method accepting a type parameter, you usually have reusable code where you gain from keeping the type information at compile time.

Comment: @Thilo using type parameter, you can add type bounds in a more complicated scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
```

This `[A]` here is the type parameter. This function definition allows you to provide any type as argument for this type parameter.

```
// If you wanted to use an Int
layout[Int](5)

// If you wanted to use a String
layout[String]("OMG")

// If you wanted to one of your classes
case class AwesomeClass(i: Int, s: String)

layout[AwesomeClass](AwesomeClass(5, "omg"))
```

Also... In this method `def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"`, it is specified that the function parameter `x` is of `type A`, Scala can use this information to infer the type parameter from the function parameter `x`.

So you actually do not need to provide the `type argument` when using the method, so you can actually write the above code in a less verbose manner like following,

```
// As we provided `i : Int` as argument `x`,
// Scala will infer that type `A` is `Int` in this call
val i: Int = 5
layout(i)

// Scala will infer that type `A` is `String` in this call
layout("OMG")

// If you wanted to one of your classes
case class AwesomeClass(i: Int, s: String)

// Scala will infer that type `A` is `AwesomeClass` in this call
layout(AwesomeClass(5, "omg"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I made this diagram below in order to generalize the syntaxes for constants, variables and functions.

[Syntax combinations to declare Constants, Variables and Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N8W7.png)